# ORDER BY - many-to-many MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following problem:
I have 'content' table, which keeps main posts and objects in the system, 'custom_field' table, which enables use to add any custom field to a post and 'content_data' table, which holds custom field values.
[image: Simplified database diagram]

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_content` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `cms_content_data` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `custom_field_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `key` (`value`,`content_id`,`custom_field_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `content_id` (`content_id`),
 KEY `custom_field_id` (`custom_field_id`),
 KEY `value` (`value`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `cms_custom_field` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Now, I want to be able to ORDER result set BY custom field value.
Both custom_field.name column and content_data.value column are indexed, but that does not seem to help and the query is very slow. content_data.custom_field_id is certainly indexed as well.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `content`.`id`, `content_data`.`value` AS `title_sort` 
FROM `content` 
INNER JOIN `content_data` ON `content_data`.`content_id` = `content`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field` ON `custom_field`.`id` = `content_data`.`custom_field_id`
WHERE `custom_field`.`name` = 'title_sort'
ORDER BY `title_sort`
```

Is there any way to do it in a more optimized way?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need (at least) an index on `content_data(custom_field_id)`. BTW: your LEFT JOIN will be converted to an INNER JOIN because of your WHERE clause.

Comment: Oh, custom_field_id has an index. I thought, it was too obvious for me to mention.

Comment: Index on your ORDER BY clause also...Is it fast without the ORDER BY?

Comment: When asking performance questions for MySQL you should post results of [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) and [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: Removing ORDER BY does not improve performance, but changes the EXPLAIN PLAN (order by makes it use temporary and filesort).

Comment: Added create table and explain.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to ORDER result set BY custom field value. Both
>   custom_field.name column and content_data.value column are indexed

You have entitled `content_data.value` as the column to sort by. That is a varchar(255) column. The real 'title_sort' is an indexed varchar(50) column from `custom_field.name`.

This is closer to your described requirement:

```
SELECT 
           `content`.`id`
         , `custom_field`.`name` AS `title_sort`
         , `content_data`.`value`AS whatever_this_is
FROM  `custom_field`
INNER JOIN `content_data`  ON `custom_field`.`id` = `content_data`.`custom_field_id`
INNER JOIN `content` ON `content_data`.`content_id` = `content`.`id`
WHERE `custom_field`.`name` = 'title_sort'
ORDER BY `custom_field`.`name`
```

However, what you do want is very probably a sort on `content_data`.`value` .

Comment: I DO want to sort records by value :) custom_field.name will always be the same.

Comment: Yes, I got it, but that is not what you have "stated"... which leads to confusion all around. I almost deleted this answer but thought I should at least bring the inconsistency to light. **Please provide table DDL and explain plan output**

Comment: Added CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN.